# Forming piano arpeggios/accompaniment for a particular song

Tags: piano, chords, arranging, arpeggios, accompaniment

I am an intermediate self-taught pianist(Trinity Grade 5).

I learnt a beautiful arrangement of a GOT song which I found on YouTube. It had really difficult left hand patterns and the arranger seemed to have created them for that particular song only. They fit perfectly to the song and when I tried using them elsewhere, it just doesn't sound right. I hope I am clear.

I want to know how pianists create original arpeggios, get creative and what process goes into creating amazing arrangements and I want to do the same in my own arrangements and pieces. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You get better at arranging with experience.  Lots of trial-and-error.  Make sure you have the correct chords for the song you are arranging.  Decide what style of accompaniment would suit it best - flowing arpeggios, chords, or simple bassline only, etc.  Each song will have its own particular accompaniment (including chordal sequence and style) and its up to you to fashion it to suit.  Also, choosing a different style of accompaniment for the same song will change the song's character.